# too many values to unpack (expected 2) when using for loops

Tags: python, pandas, list

I keep on getting the error message : too many values to unpack (expected 2)
when I tryout the below code :

```
sheetlist = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]

for i, j in sheetlist :
    j = i +1 
    final = i.merge(j, how = "outer", on = "columnname")


final.head()
```

May anyone know how to solve this?

Here's the complete Traceback

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-54-981bc6246be4> in <module>()
      3 sheetlist = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]
      4 
----> 5 for i,j in sheetlist :
      6     j = i + 1
      7     final = i.merge(j, how = "outer", on = "columnname")

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: `for i in sheetlist`

Comment: also, try reduce merge rather than for loop

Comment: Whenever you report a Python error, include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there, including which line generated the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error is  here :

```
for i, j in sheetlist :
```

The error appears because you are trying to unpack two values from a list, which is expecting to give one by one.

Comment: Oh.. so for list I can only unpack 1 value...?

Comment: You go one by one yes.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you need `for i in sheetlist` as @not_speshal said. In addition, notice that a `for` in python isn't unlike many other languages, and will enumerate the **items** inside the list, instead of the indices.

Hence, you might want something like this: `for i in range(len(sheetlist))`, and now `i` is indeed the valid index. To access the element at index `i` in the list, use `sheetlist[i]`.